# FLutter FirebaseAuth Email verification

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

right now i try to code an own android App.
therefore i wanted to create an e-mail and password based sign-in/ sign Up which also includes an E-mail Verification service.
the problem is that, everytime i launch it in the Emulator, and try to register, it will just occure an nosuchmethod error that tells me that either the getter email or the getter sendEmailVerification()
is called on null.

pls have a look at my verification-code and tell me what i did wrong.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home.dart';






class Verification extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VerificationState createState() => _VerificationState();
}

class _VerificationState extends State<Verification> {
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User user;
  Timer timer;
  String email =  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.email.toString(); 


 Future<void> verificateEmail() async{
   User user = auth.currentUser;

   if (user != null) {
     await user.sendEmailVerification();}
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {checkEmailVerified(); });

 }
    
   
  
  
  
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("draicksmail sent to ${user.email}"),
      ),
    );
  }




  Future<void> checkEmailVerified() async{
    user = auth.currentUser;
    await user.reload();
    if (user.emailVerified){
      timer.cancel();
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Home()));
    }
  }


    
  

}
```

Comment: Could you add some more code please? It is clear though from what you have, `auth.currentUser` is null.

Comment: Thanks bro, but I‘ve defined auth with the final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance, a couple lines before. Btw The „Home()“ extends a stateless widget which is defined in  another dart file and the class „Verification()“ gets called by a ‚Navigator.of(context).push(materialpageroutebuilder(builder: (context) => Verification())),} ,

Comment: So is your `user` defined when you do the following? `User user = auth.currentUser;` ? Also please add your error message

Comment: Yes user is defined.

Comment: The error message is: NoSuchMethodError: The getter ‚email‘ was called on null tried calling email See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors

Comment: I'd recommend following this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth as your code seems like it should work as normal. There are some settings you'll need in android configuration which are mentioned here. Otherwise, `=  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.email.toString(); ` should probably go in your init state function.

Answer (score 0):

So this error is caused because `auth.currentUser` returns `null`. Therefore trying to execute a method on `null` throws an error because nothing exists on `null`.

Have you added the following to your `main()` method?

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
runApp(Home());
```

Checkout the following guide for more details https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android

Comment: Yes I’ve added these to my main

Comment: Are there any error messages on initialization?

Comment: Yeah sorry without more code or info I'm stuck, sadly. From the code you have provided it *should* work.